# Ion-toggle button does not show correct toggle - Ionic 3, Angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ion-toggle

I have my ion-toggle defined and I have set 2 properties to it as below:

```
<ion-toggle [checked]="storageStatus" (ionChange)="updateItem()"></ion-toggle>
```

everything is working just fine, I am able to toggle and change values to the localStorage and so on. But I am not sure why toggle button falls back to off state (or false state). when I move to another page and comeback.

**Only Toggle button shown "visually" falls to Off state and not the values. I want button to be in the state in which I have set in localStorage while toggling.**

The toggle value is correct and so binding value too.

```
storageStatus: any;

updateItem(){
  this.storageStatus = !this.storageStatus;
  window.localStorage.setItem('item', this.storageStatus);
}
```

## Entire Code - update

**Below Solution works for me now. I am not sure if its a good approach or not.**

**app.component.ts** (when app loads setItem to true)

```
ngOnInit() {
  window.localStorage.setItem('item', 'true');
}
```

**typescript file**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-settings',
  templateUrl: 'settings.html',
})
export class SettingsPage{

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private toastCtrl: ToastController) {
  }

  //THIS IS THE LINE THAT DID THE TRICK OF SHOWING ION-TOGGLE AS PER item value
  storageStatus: string = window.localStorage.getItem('item');

  updateItem(){
    window.localStorage.setItem('item', this.storageStatus);
    this.presentToast();

  }


    presentToast() {
      console.log("present Toast");
      const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'New Changes Updated',
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'bottom'
    });

    toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
      console.log('Dismissed toast');
    });

    toast.present();
  }
}
```

**html file**

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-item-group>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Item Status</ion-label>
     <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="storageStatus"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>

    </ion-item-group>
    <button ion-button block color="light" (click)="updateItem()">Save Changes</button>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: well how are you setting the value when navigating to page? There's not enough code to reproduce this issue ;)

Comment: Could you please add the code of the entire page, so we can take a look at how these items are being initialized?

Comment: @sebaferreras 2-way binding alone did not do the trick, I had to add these : `storageStatus: string = window.localStorage.getItem('item');` For some reason I cant use boolean but string as things stored in localStorage are in string

Comment: I would save the `ion-toggle` value to a boolean value instead of string. You can convert the localestorage string when you get the value and also when you set the value.

Answer (score 2):

I think marvstar gave right answer but solution was not proper.

You need to use both two way binding and `checked`.

When page initializes you have to check what is current value in localstorage.

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.storageStatus=localstorage.getItem('item');
}
```

**In HTML :**  Add condition in `[checked]`

```
<ion-toggle [checked]="storageStatus == true?true:false"  [(ngModel)]="storageStatus" (ionChange)="eventChange($event)" ></ion-toggle>
```

**In TS file** Add eventChange method and use $event to use actual toggle values :

```
 eventChange(toggleValue){
     console.log(toggleValue._value)
     if(toggleValue._value==true){
       let i=true;
     }else if(toggleValue._value==false){
       let i=false;
     }

    localStorage.setItem('storageItem',i);

  }
```

Comment: " == true?true:false" saved my night... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just use two way databinding instead of one way and use the ngModel instead of checked.

Change `[checked]="storageStatus"`

to `[(ngModel)]="storageStatus"`

I'm using it as follow:

```
<ion-toggle checked="false" [(ngModel)]="settings.showIcon"></ion-toggle>
```

Comment: that's what I did initially, then moved to one way binding. I will fall back to 2-way binding. can you tell me what is settings.showIcon here? do I need this: `(ionChange)="updateItem()"` can you show exactly what needs to be done both in `<ion-toggle>` tag and in typescript file.

Comment: you don't need the ionChange listener because the two way binding will do that work of changing the boolean value for you.